# What should our response to code-only answers be?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I've seen a lot of code-only answers in the Low-Quality review queue. What should our response to these answers be? Although they have all been flagged as low-quality, I've been posting a comment welcoming new users and asking them to explain how their answer works, then clicking "Looks Good" (because I don't think they should be deleted).

Wouldn't it be nicer to add an explanatory comment asking for an explanation rather than flag or downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of the low-quality flags are auto-generated by Community. I wouldn't take them too seriously.

Comment: That makes much more sense. I was wondering who would flag all these answers instead of commenting. However, I wonder why it feels as if I'm the only one doing these comments.

Comment: @Quincunx the queue is usually quite empty here. Also I think commenting + looks good is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Chris Jester-Young](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1090/3755). I do not take those auto-generated flags too seriously. And I add this: If possible (normally it is), edit the answer to improve its formatting. If the answer is salvageable, go on and save it (ditto for questions). I am doing this for sometime, the result was that I got the first Strunk & White badge of the site.

Answer (score 2):

I think code-only answers are, in general, legitimate.

[In some cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3093/3544), if you understand the language you don't need explanations.
[In other cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3044/3544), there's no real way to appreciate an answer without them.

But I wouldn't say we need to ban them or something.